# mongoDB with non-standard UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, jsp, mongodb, character-encoding, websphere

I got a problem when inserting unusual characters into MongoDB.

The characters are as follows: é è í ì á à... etc

basically, characters that are mostly used in latin countries.

when I insert it by script (since if I try it in the console it replies "non-utf-8 character") it does it just fine, well, it adds it to the collection, but with some weird characters.

if I do a find, with let's say, "Olá" and I have a field that gets searched with "Olá" but with those weird characters, it replies the data on the field I want just fine...
however, if in that field there is some sort of character which isn't your standard english chartype, it displays something like this:

`�til?`

Is there any way that I can handle this?

I'm using Websphere Portal server, the PortletView file outputs in UTF-8, the servlet handles the inputted data to encode it in UTF-8 when sending to the db for the query, and it also handles the data it retrieves from the DB into UTF-8 (just to be sure).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that a servlet filter isn't causing the request to use the incorrect character encoding. This can be caused by calling one of the `getParameterXXX()` family of methods on the `ServletRequest` *before* setting the request's character encoding to `UTF-8`.

Comment: well I am doing a conversion when I do the transmission of strings between the DB and the servlet...
might be a problem when bringing it from the servlet to the portletview...

Comment: So it seems that in the `doPost()` of the servlet, right before I do the `response.getWriter()` call I should do the following:

`String contentType= "text/html;charset=UTF-8";`
`response.setContentType(contentType);`

if you'd like you may post this as an answer and I'll accept it, since I can't seem to post an answer to my own question this soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that a servlet filter isn't causing the request to use the incorrect character encoding. This can be caused by calling one of the `getParameterXXX()` family of methods on the `ServletRequest` before setting the request's character encoding to `UTF-8`.

The [servlet spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index2.html) states that ISO8859-1 is used by default. See *SRV.3.9 Request data encoding*.

Also make sure that the response uses the correct content type (with encoding). As posted above in comment:

```
String contentType= "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
response.setContentType(contentType);
```